# Annotations showing wrong image

Tags: swift, swift3, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkannotationview

Is there any way that annotations might show other images then it should supose ? Is it a way to fix that ?

I've got a werid problem. After my clusters going to evolve to the single annotations then after updating ( zoom out - zoom in ) they images going to be diferent then it should be. After debuging it says that the color of the pin view image is the one which I suposed. Where I could hook up yet to see the exact data ? Maybe something after `viewFor` which get invoked.

Here is a logic how am I doing this.

The dictionary to knows witch model is on the top of the added annotations.

```
var dicAnnotations = [FBAnnotation : MyModel]()
```

Through the loop of `[MyModel]` i am appending data to the array of the `[FBAnnotation]` which is needed for saving them via `FBClusteringManager`. Then in the same time while the new annotation is added to the `[FBAnnotation]` I am adding

```
self.dicAnnotations[fbAnnotation] = objModel
```

to know which annotation have which object.

So as we know how I am soring the data of annotations, how Am I indexing them, lets have a look on the delegate of the `MKMapView`.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
            let mapBoundsWidth = Double(self.mapView.bounds.size.width)
            let mapRectWidth = self.mapView.visibleMapRect.size.width
            let scale = mapBoundsWidth / mapRectWidth

            let annotationArray = self.clusterManager.clusteredAnnotations(withinMapRect: self.mapView.visibleMapRect, zoomScale:scale)
            for ann in annotationArray {
                if ann is FBAnnotation {
                    let a = ann as! FBAnnotation
                    print("Here u are , my color is : \(self.dicAnnotations[a]!.lineColor)")
                }
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.clusterManager.display(annotations: annotationArray, onMapView: self.mapView)
            }
        }
    }
```

The for loop is for checking if the annotation is the one which should be - and it is!

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        var reuseId = ""
        if annotation is FBAnnotationCluster {
            reuseId = "Cluster"
            var clusterView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: reuseId)
            if clusterView == nil {
                clusterView = FBAnnotationClusterView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId, configuration: FBAnnotationClusterViewConfiguration.default())
            } else {
                clusterView?.annotation = annotation
            }

            return clusterView
        } 

else {
            let ann = annotation as! FBAnnotation
            var pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: "Pin")
                pinView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: ann, reuseIdentifier: "Pin")

                var modelType = dicAnnotations[ann]?.modelType
                modelType = modelType?.modelTypeToString(modelType: modelType!)
                let modelColor = dicAnnotations[ann]?.lineColor
                let modelDirection = dicAnnotations[ann]?.withHeading360
                print("\(modelType!)_\(modelColor!)")
                pinView?.image = UIImage(named: "\(modelType!)_\(modelColor!)")?.rotated(by: Measurement(value: modelDirection!, unit: .degrees))
            return pinView
        }
    }
```

How it looks in the stack call which I am able get :

```
Here u are , my color is : yellow
(lldb) po dicAnnotations[ann]
▿ Optional<MyModel>
  ▿ some : <Project.MyModel: 0x101b656f0>


(lldb) po dicAnnotations[ann]?.lineColor
▿ Optional<String>
  - some : "yellow"
```

From :

```
// viewFor
... else { pinView?.annotation = ann  } ...
```

Any ideas ? It shows me would say "random colored image".

Thanks in advance!

**Solution**

I've edited the delegate `viewFor`. Deleted the `if pinView == null` condition and else as well. Somehow it was not working like it suposed to.